# import data from web stream in c++

Tags: c++, stream, live

i was wondering if is possible to import data from a live stream from a web site and perform computation on the data in real time? if this is possible what is the most efficient(computationally fast) way of doing it? thank you for any help or commpents.

Comment: There is a variety of streaming protocols.  For some, tools may exist, for others, not so much.
It would help to indicate what streaming protocol you want to capture.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+http+library

Comment: Tagging something as 'streams' at the same time as tagging it 'c++' might going to give the wrong impression (streams in C++ are a distinct concept from a data stream from the internet).  Change the tag to 'streaming-media' IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). A curl handle can have a function called each time new data comes in.

Answer (score 0):

The VLC from VideoLan.org is a free open source player that can render almost any codec and can handle almost any kind of stream.  That's probably your best starting point, and depending on what you're doing your objective may be better served by writing a plugin for that application.  Its a pretty open ended question though.

Answer (score 0):

What type of data are you talking about streaming?  Perhaps [socket programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) is what you need.